# Error: Command errored out with exit status 1: (really long command)

Tags: python, sage

```
$ cd surface_dynamics
$ pip3 install .
Processing /Users/jacobelection/surface_dynamics
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/m8/lmzlkfq11wj3rn17q7xm7g2m0000gn/T/pip-req-build-ubkp2yci/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/m8/lmzlkfq11wj3rn17q7xm7g2m0000gn/T/pip-req-build-ubkp2yci/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/m8/lmzlkfq11wj3rn17q7xm7g2m0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-jhapggrl
         cwd: /private/var/folders/m8/lmzlkfq11wj3rn17q7xm7g2m0000gn/T/pip-req-build-ubkp2yci/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/m8/lmzlkfq11wj3rn17q7xm7g2m0000gn/T/pip-req-build-ubkp2yci/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        import sage.all
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/m8/lmzlkfq11wj3rn17q7xm7g2m0000gn/T/pip-req-build-ubkp2yci/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise ValueError("this package currently installs only inside SageMath (http://www.sagemath.org)\n"
    ValueError: this package currently installs only inside SageMath (http://www.sagemath.org)
    If you are using Ubuntu with Sage installed from the official apt repository, run
    first in a console "$ source /usr/share/sagemath/bin/sage-env"

    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///Users/jacobelection/surface_dynamics. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How could I fixed these problem? My python version is 3.8.3. macOS Big Sur 11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command needs to be run with the `pip` that
corresponds to SageMath's Python, which would
depend on the way SageMath was installed:

- built from source?
- from binaries from the SageMath download page?
- from Marc Culler's SageMath app?
- via Homebrew cask?
- via Conda?

One way to go is to install the SageMath macOS app from

- https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS/releases

and run the `Recommended.pkg` installer.

Then instead of

```
pip3 install .
```

run

```
sage --pip install .
```

Or if you installed SageMath via Conda, make sure to
first activate the corresponding Conda environment:

```
conda activate sage
pip install .
```

In case of doubt, check what pip is going to be called
with commands such as:

```
which pip
ls -halF $(which pip)
which pip3
ls -halF $(which pip3)
```

Comment: i did this thing ，but got this problem

Comment: When I instead pip3 by sage --pip3 I got same answer